# Attempt to global 'creatureBody' - Nil Value

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to have my information encapsulated in one variable and it is having a hard time working in my Corona file.

I have removed the line that changes the color but I am still having some sort of functional error

```lua
function CreateBeast(parent, hasParent)
    hugWall = math.random(4); -- 1 left, 2 top, 3 right, 4 bottom
    red = math.random(255);
    green = math.random(255);
    blue = math.random(255);
    if hugWall == 1 then
        xCoordinates = 0 + radiusCircle;
        yCoordinates = math.random(480);
    elseif hugWall == 2 then
        xCoordinates = math.random(320);
        yCoordinates = 480 - radiusCircle;
    elseif hugWall == 3 then
        xCoordinates = 320 - radiusCircle;
        yCoordinates = math.random(480);
    elseif hugWall == 4 then
        xCoordinates = math.random(320);
        yCoordinates = 0 + radiusCircle;
    end
    if hasParent == 1 then
        creature = 
        {
            creatureTitle = parent.creatureTitle;
            size =  parent.size;
            speed = parent.speed;
            x = xCoordinates;
            y = yCoordinates;
            creatureBody = display.newCircle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, radiusCircle);
            creatureBody:setFillColor(parent);
        }
    else
        creature =
        {
            creatureTitle = creatureIterator;
            creatureIterator = creatureIterator + 1;
            size = 1;
            speed = 1;
            x = xCoordinates;
            y = yCoordinates;
            creatureBody = display.newCircle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, radiusCircle);
            creatureBody:setFillColor(red, green, blue);
        }
    end
    return creature
end

creatureArray = {}; 
for i = 0, starterNumOfCreatures , 1
do
    creature = CreateBeast(0,0);
    creatureArray[i] = creature;

end
```

It keeps throwing in errors of attempting to access global variable. It specifically has a problem with the line that changes the color of the body while it is being created in the for loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the actual, full error message (full text, line number...)?

Comment: You refer to `creatureBody` inside two table constructors without defining it as a variable. Maybe you meant to call that method after `creature` is defined?

Comment: It has a problem with the setFillColor when it is being made in the four loop.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says: `creatureBody` is `nil` and you are trying to call it. You can't do that. Consider this fragment of your code:

```
if hasParent == 1 then
    creature = 
    {
        creatureTitle = parent.creatureTitle;
        size =  parent.size;
        speed = parent.speed;
        x = xCoordinates;
        y = yCoordinates;
        creatureBody = display.newCircle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, radiusCircle);
        creatureBody:setFillColor(parent);
    }
else
    creature =
    {
        creatureTitle = creatureIterator;
        creatureIterator = creatureIterator + 1;
        size = 1;
        speed = 1;
        x = xCoordinates;
        y = yCoordinates;
        creatureBody = display.newCircle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, radiusCircle);
        creatureBody:setFillColor(red, green, blue);
    }
end
```

When you are calling `setFillColor` there isn't any `creatureBody` available in local or global scope and it's expected since it isn't defined anywhere in provided code.

You can fix it by e.g. moving out circle constructor call:

```
local creatureBody = display.newCircle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, radiusCircle)
creature =
{
    creatureTitle = creatureIterator;
    creatureIterator = creatureIterator + 1;
    size = 1;
    speed = 1;
    x = xCoordinates;
    y = yCoordinates;
    creatureBody = creatureBody;
    body:setFillColor(red, green, blue);
}
```

Please do note that return values of `setFillColor` will be inserted into `creature`. It really makes me wonder if this is desired behaviour.

Please refer to [Lua Reference Manual §3.4.9](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) if you have trouble understanding why `creatureBody` is not available or why `setFillColor` returns will be inserted into `creature`.